# Why does fstab use UUID instead of the actual file system name?

Tags: filesystems, mount, disk-usage, fstab

For example, this is the first line of my `/etc/fstab`:

```
UUID=050e1e34-39e6-4072-a03e-ae0bf90ba13a    /    ext4    errors=remount-ro    0    1
```

And here's the output of `df -h` command (reporting free disk space):

```
honey@bunny:~$ df -T

Filesystem     Type     1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/vda       ext4      30832636 4884200  24359188  17% /
none           tmpfs            4       0         4   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev           devtmpfs    498172      12    498160   1% /dev
tmpfs          tmpfs       101796     320    101476   1% /run
none           tmpfs         5120       0      5120   0% /run/lock
none           tmpfs       508972       0    508972   0% /run/shm
none           tmpfs       102400       0    102400   0% /run/user
```

1. From the two is it okay to deduce that `UUID=050e1e34-39e6-4072-a03e-ae0bf90ba13a` represents `/dev/vda` given that the first column in `fstab` is `<file system>`?
2. So, would it be okay if I modified `/etc/fstab` to this?

   ```
   /dev/vda    /    ext4    errors=remount-ro    0    1
   ```
3. **EDIT:** If yes (to above question), why does the `sudo blkid` command show a different UUID for `/dev/vda`?

   ```
   $ sudo blkid

   /dev/vda: LABEL="DOROOT" UUID="6f469437-4935-44c5-8ac6-53eb54a9af26" TYPE="ext4"
   ```

   What am I missing here?

   **Answer:** I'd conclude (3) to be a bug in the cloud of my host. So yes, the UUID reported by `blkid` (or `ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid`) should be the same as the one used in `/etc/fstab`.

Comment: Check the UUID with `sudo blkid` command.

Comment: @AvinashRaj Hmm, weirdly, the `sudo blkid` command outputs a different UUID for `/dev/vda`. This adds to my confusion. :) (Updated question.)

Comment: It is not a good sign that the blkid command shows a different UUID - please check the current UUID with `ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid''.
Since its vda, might it be that the underlying VM infrastructure changed something?

Comment: @liquidat This is the output I got: `lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 Jun 18 11:04 6f469437-4935-44c5-8ac6-53eb54a9af26 -> ../../vda`. As for your other question, I'll contact the web host about that.

Comment: I'd say that the machine might not reboot since the fstab entry is plain wrong. Could be a cloned disk or something. I take it that there is no other device which has the UUID given in fstab?

Comment: @liquidat (1) The machine is rebooting just fine. (2) I shut the VM down a couple of times to take a snapshot. Could that be it? (3) That's the only uncommented line in `/etc/fstab`.

Comment: No idea, sorry.

Comment: as for the uuid, the only relevant thing is tune2fs -l I think. the uuid used for the root device upon reboot is probably set in the grub config.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The advantage of using the UUID is that it is independent from the actual device number the operating system gives your hard disk.

Imagine you add another hard disk to the system, and for some reason the OS decides that your old disk is now `sdb` instead of `sda`.

Your boot process would be screwed up if `fstab` points to the device name. But in case of the UUIDs, it is fine.

More detailed information about UUIDs can also be found on the blog post ["UUIDs and Linux: Everything you ever need to know"](http://liquidat.wordpress.com/2013/03/13/uuids-and-linux-everything-you-ever-need-to-know/)

Comment: yep. even without adding a new disk, your kernel may decide to just swap two of your drives' dev mounts one day. See https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Persistent_block_device_naming

Comment: what happens if I want to clone the image to another disk, which have a different UUID?

Comment: There's at least one situation where UUIDs are less useful: if you clone an entire disk, then reboot, you may get partitions mounting from either disk, or the wrong disk.

Comment: That's true - check the linked blog post, it even has a section when not to use them.

Comment: If you clone the disk you should change the UUID on the new disk. tune2fs xfs_admin or reiserfstune can do that depending on your filesystem.

Answer (score 3):

> In that case, can I modify /etc/fstab to this?

You *can* and it will *probably* be okay, but most likely it would be better to leave the UUID.

[UUIDs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UUID) are arbitrary strings used to identify, in this case, a partition on a block device; its stored with the partition itself, and can be assigned a different one if desired (sort of like MAC addresses).

The advantage of using the UUID is that it is unmistakable, whereas `/dev/vda` is not; it *could* happen that it ends up being a different drive at boot time, although this may be totally theoretical in context (e.g., because you only have one drive of a particular type).

Another more subtle example of where using the device name can cause a problem would be the recent switch on some systems to using [consistent network device names](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Features/ConsistentNetworkDeviceNaming).  If this occurred as an upgrade and you used a hardcoded device name in a network script somewhere, it would break.  A parallel example WRT block devices might be a kernel or udev upgrade which changes the naming scheme.

One point of UUIDs is to make these kind of things possible and painless.  So while you *can* use the device name, there is no advantage to doing so *unless* (e.g.) you have a system where you swap different drives in.  In other words, if you don't have a good reason to do that, *stick with the UUID*.

Comment: Okay. So what explains the different UUIDs for `/dev/vda` in `/etc/fstab` and reported by `blkid`? (Please see the updated question if you haven't.)

Comment: Rather than asking in an update, you should ask that as a separate question ("Why is my mounted partition UUID different than the one in fstab?").

Answer (score 2):

You can do `man fstab` for a fairly concise read on the contents and semantics of the `/etc/fstab` file.  On my x86, fairly up-to-date Arch linux server, `man fstab` gives me this:

```
The second field ... describes  the mount point for the filesystem.
```

So, yes, `/dev/vda` apparently is one of many names for some device, as is `UUID=050e1e34-39e6-4072-a03e-ae0bf90ba13a`, given that both names appear to mount on "/".

If you look in the directory `/dev/disk/by-uuid/` you can see symbolic links that point to things like `/dev/sda1`, `/dev/sdb1` on my server. This might be another way to check your hypothesis. `/dev/disk` has subdirectories `by-id`, `by-path`, `by-uuid` which all appear to be alternate names for the same device.

Comment: In that case, the problem (as updated in my question) is that I get two different UUIDs for `/dev/vda`! Please see the question one more time.

Comment: If I answered the original question, it might be a good idea to mark it "answered" and write a new question, just so you don't collect irrelevant answers, answers that work with the original and not the modified question.