# Creating a new partition with parted for a new hard drive: when mounted, it is much smaller than expected. Why?

Tags: partition, hard-disk, parted

I attached a new hard drive (6TB, `/dev/sdb`) to my computer (Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS x64), and tried to create a new partition as follows:

```
sudo lshw -C disk                # Checking the location of the new drive. It is /dev/sdb.     
sudo parted /dev/sdb mklabel gpt # Creating the GUID Partition Table (GPT)
sudo parted /dev/sdb print       # Checking that the GPT has been created
sudo parted /dev/sdb print unit MB print free # see 6001175MB size
sudo parted --align optimal /dev/sdb mkpart primary ext4 0% 6001175MB # Creating partition
```

Then I `sudo nano /etc/fstab` and added the line (I'll use the [`UUID`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/137868/16704) once I fix this issue):

```
/dev/sdb1       /crimea ext4 defaults   0       0       # 6 TB: /dev/sdb
```

and remounted `/etc/fstab`:

```
sudo mount -a # Remount /etc/fstab without rebooting
```

When I run `df -h`, I do see the new partition, however its size it's much more about that I expected (190M, whereas I expected around 6TB)

```
/dev/sdb1                      190M   45M  131M  26% /crimea
```

Why?

---

`sudo parted /dev/sdb print` outputs the following, so the new partition should be 6TB from my understanding:

```
Model: ATA ST6000NM0024-1HT (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 6001GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name     Flags
 1      1049kB  6001GB  6001GB  ext4         primary
```

`sudo lshw -C volume` however more or less agrees with `df`. It says the partition is of size `200MiB` (while `df` says `190M`):

```
 *-volume
       description: EXT4 volume
       vendor: Linux
       physical id: 1
       bus info: scsi@1:0.0.0,1
       logical name: /dev/sdb1
       logical name: /crimea
       version: 1.0
       serial: c3554308-795b-46db-9855-8a974c55a1ce
       size: 200MiB
       capacity: 5589GiB
       capabilities: journaled extended_attributes huge_files dir_nlink extents ext4 ext2 initialized
       configuration: created=2016-06-24 14:56:55 filesystem=ext4 lastmountpoint=/boot modified=2016-07-01 17:15:55 mount.fstype=ext4 mount.options=rw,relatime,data=ordered mounted=2016-07-01 17:07:19 name=primary state=mounted
```

Comment: I ran into behavior like that when using tools that didn't know about GPT (only MBR).  But I don't see clues in your question...

Comment: @ThomasDickey Thanks, yes that's why I avoided fdisk :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`parted` just sets partition labels; doesn't make the filesystem.

Looking at the `configuration` line I see

```
lastmountpoint=/boot
```

This is telling me that after you partitioned the disk you missed the `mke2fs -t ext4` step on the new partition and so you're seeing an older set of data from an older filesystem.

(My guess would be that your `sdb` disk used to be a primary disk with an OS boot partition on it).

So umount the filesystem then run the `mke2fs -t ext4` command then you can mount it and have the full size.

Comment: Thanks, I unmounted (`sudo unmount /dev/sdb1`), ran`sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdb1`,  remounted and it worked. I'm surprised that sudo lshw -C volume has the same output (`size: 200MiB`). Any idea why?

Comment: `lshw` shows the wrong results, even though `df` now shows correct?  Odd...  Dunno about that one.  Maybe it's cached information somewhere?  Just guessing...

Comment: Thanks, I have asked the question separately:  [lshw and df see a different partition size (5.5 TB vs. 200 MiB). Why?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/303279/16704)