# lshw and df see a different partition size (5.5 TB vs. 200 MiB). Why?

Tags: partition, disk-usage

`lshw` and `df -h` see a different partition size (5.5 TB vs. 200 MiB) for one of the partitions of my computer (Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS x64). I'm pretty sure `df -h` is right, as when I created the partition with `parted`, I configured the partition to be of size 5.5 TB. ([here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/303235/16704) are the instructions I used to create the partition if it matters). Also, I tried to place more than 200 MiB of files in that partition and it worked fine.

How comes `lshw` doesn't seem the same size as `df -h`?

Below is the output of the two commands (the partition in question is `/dev/sdb1`, mounted to `/crimea`)

```
username@server:/crimea$ df -h
Filesystem                     Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                            63G   12K   63G   1% /dev
tmpfs                           13G  1.7M   13G   1% /run
/dev/dm-2                      923G   54G  823G   7% /
none                           4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
none                           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none                            63G     0   63G   0% /run/shm
none                           100M     0  100M   0% /run/user
/dev/mapper/vg_system-openafs  2.9G   49M  2.7G   2% /var/cache/openafs
AFS                            2.0T     0  2.0T   0% /afs
/dev/sdb1                      5.5T   58M  5.2T   1% /crimea
username@server:/crimea$ sudo lshw -C volume
  *-volume:0
       description: LVM Physical Volume
       vendor: Linux
       physical id: 1
       bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,1
       logical name: /dev/sda1
       serial: S3pp6Q-ZaaU-1Y3I-DE05-0cdd-xYZZ-4WvaKP
       size: 953GiB
       capabilities: multi lvm2
       configuration: name=primary
  *-volume:1
       description: BIOS Boot partition
       vendor: EFI
       physical id: 2
       bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,2
       logical name: /dev/sda2
       serial: ce1dec5b-2888-49fd-a770-1f159765f7c5
       capacity: 1023KiB
       capabilities: nofs
       configuration: name=primary
  *-volume
       description: EXT4 volume
       vendor: Linux
       physical id: 1
       bus info: scsi@1:0.0.0,1
       logical name: /dev/sdb1
       logical name: /crimea
       version: 1.0
       serial: c3552308-705b-99db-9855-8e456c96a1ce
       size: 200MiB
       capacity: 5589GiB
       capabilities: journaled extended_attributes huge_files dir_nlink extents ext4 ext2 initialized
       configuration: created=2016-06-24 14:56:55 filesystem=ext4 lastmountpoint=/boot modified=2016-07-01 17:15:55 mount.fstype=ext4 mount.options=rw,relatime,data=ordered mounted=2016-07-01 17:07:19 name=primary state=mounted
```

Comment: The `lshw` appears to still be showing the pre-mke2fs settings (eg "lastmountpoint" value).  Odd!

Comment: `df` makes system calls, `lshw` actually reads the disk.  If you look at the `lshw` code you can see that [it sets `size` to whatever the partition gives](https://github.com/lyonel/lshw/blob/master/src/core/partitions.cc#L397), and then makes a huge `do-while` calculating the size and putting it into `capacity`.  Not sure where the call to `getCapacity()` is taking the info from, though.

Comment: @grochmal You're reading the wrong part of the code: this is for extended partitions. For a partition containing an ext4 filesystem, the size is set in [`detect_ext2`](https://github.com/lyonel/lshw/blob/c2cebe30e4c406d7ff1d4dc58b95bc3eef319b4e/src/core/volumes.cc#L254). I don't understand how that's coming up to 200MB.

Comment: @Gilles - good point (`ext` confusion on my side).  But yeah, I cannot see either from where that size can be coming from.  I'd like OP to try it again after restartig the machine (maybe, just maybe, it is some cache in the disk firmware?)

Comment: @grochmal I will let you know how it goes after the restart, but since it's a server it doesn't happen often. Also, `sudo blkid /dev/sdb1` shows a different UUID than `sudo lshw -C volume`, so it does look like something gets cached somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

But they do show the same, it's right there in `lshw` output: `capacity: 5589GiB`. Now, a better question would be what is the difference between lshw `capacity` and `size`